# What is the significance of MLE = arithmetic mean?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

I am reading Jaynes' book on probability theory.

He explains that a particular derivation for the normal distribution was first recognized by Gauss, when he asked the following question.
Say we have a sampling distribution $f_m(x)$ with location parameter $m$, so that $f_m(x)=f_0(x-m)$. Now assume we sample $X=\{x_0,...,x_n\}$ from this.

Now assume we place a restriction on $f$: **the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) of $m$ given $X$ must be equal to the sample mean $\bar x$.**

The only probability distribution $f$ that satiafies this constraint is the normal distribution.

I find this first of all quite surprising, but more importantly, **what is the significance of the requirement that MLE$(m)$=$\bar x$? Why should we pay any attention to the distribution that happens to satisfy that requirement?**

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to look at some simple non-normal distributions and explicitly calculate the MLE of their mean, to see the manner of deviation from the sample mean.

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting requirement because it means that when you're looking for an estimator of the mean of the distribution, you just need to take the empirical mean and you get an excellent estimator (MLE, hence BLUE).

Two statements sound weird to me however:

- *"The only probability distribution f that satisfies this constraint is the normal distribution."*

I would think that the uniform distribution on [m-1,m+1] also satisfies it.

- *"The normal distribution was first recognized by Gauss"*

Although he didn't fully appreciate its importance, Laplace studied the normal distribution a few years before Gauss' birth.

Comment: I think the exponential distribution might also have this property, though maybe I made a calculation error.

Comment: That is a practical benefit, surely, but it doesn't say anything about why the resulting distribution is significant theoretically, or why the normal distribution should pop up in so many theorems and that it plays such a fundamental role in statistics.

Comment: By the way laplace became an adult roughly at the tkme of gauss's birth, so that can't be possible. But yes I should edit it

Comment: Also, I suppose you can see that linear function as the limit of the standard deviation to infinity of the normal distribution, cut off beyond the edges of the sample points where its values are irrelevant.